# font is not embeded while converting html to pdf using itext and Flying Saucer

Tags: java, flying-saucer

Hi here is my code to generate pdf from a html source , html got perfectly but some what pdf misses that font and text

```
try{
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
        buf.append("<html><head><style>@font-face {font-family:gautami;src:url(C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\font\\gautami.ttf);-fs-pdf-font-embed: embed;-fs-pdf-font-encoding: Identity-H;} .col{color:red;}</style></head><body style='font-family:gautami'>");
        //List<File> fil = fileGallaryDAO.getNews();
       // for (File movie : fil) {
            // create the snippet


            buf.append("<div class='col'> &#3120;&#3134;&#3127;&#3149;&#3103;&#3149;&#3120; &#3125;&#3135;&#3117;&#3100;&#3112; &#3093;&#3147;&#3128;&#3074; &#3120;&#3134;&#3100;&#3149;&#3119;&#3134;&#3074;&#3095; &#3128;&#3125;&#3120;&#3107;</div>");

            // use the snippet for the HTML page
       // }

        buf.append("<div class='col'>fgfdhd</div></body></html>");
        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont (
            "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\font\\gautami.ttf",
             "UTF-8",
             BaseFont.EMBEDDED
        );
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\htmlpdf\\new.html"));
         out.println(buf.toString());
         out.flush();
         out.close();
        //renderer.setDocument(buf.toString());
        renderer.setDocument(new java.io.File("C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\htmlpdf\\new.html"));
        String outputFile = "C:\\Documents and Settings\\Administrator\\Desktop\\htmlpdf\\newpdf.pdf";
        OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

        renderer.layout();
        renderer.createPDF(os);
        os.flush();
        os.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

html file output :

```
రాష్ట్ర విభజన కోసం రాజ్యాంగ సవరణ
fgfdhd
```

pdf file output:

```
fgfdhd
```

even fonts are not embedded in pdf and  text was missed ?

Comment: You might make sure the doctype is set correctly.

Comment: How did you solve this?